# Creating a custom ubuntu ISO

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image

I want to create a custom ubuntu ISO (This ISO will contain all the packages with the latest updates released till date).
Something along the lines of

- Take the pristine ubuntu ISO
- Download the updates from some ubuntu update repositories
- Re-create the ISO?

How should I go about this?

Comment: are you trying to create an up-to-date LiveCD? or simply a CD ISO with the package updates?

Comment: I want to create an ISO with all the packages, and latest updates under main, and restricted components. BTW I don't see the packages (*.deb) on the repository URL http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/. 
For example I can view all the latest rpms for CentOS on http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/

Comment: It does not needs to be a live CD.

Comment: I will be using the server ISO, which is not a live CD

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has Simple-CDD in its repos. At least for me, it does not seem to be working with Ubuntu though.

The Ubuntu Wiki [has instructions about CD customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization) but I could not get custom GPG key working. In order to solve this, have a look at [this Unix.SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97520/how-do-i-add-custom-gpg-key-to-ubuntu-debian-installer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of possibilities:

- [Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://uck.sourceforge.net/)

  > Ubuntu Customization Kit is a tool that helps you customizing official Ubuntu Live CDs (including Kubuntu/Xubuntu and Edubuntu) to your needs. You can add any package to the live system, for example language packs, or applications.
- [Live CD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization?action=show&redirect=LiveCDCustomization%2F6.06) on the Ubuntu Wiki

Answer (score 1):

Canonical runs daily builds for most of their Ubuntu releases.

Here is Lucid Lynx (10.04 LTS): http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/lucid/daily/current/

For other images/versions look at the home directory of that website.