# How to make your own pre-configured stand-alone ubuntu install disk

Tags: ubuntu, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a custom ubuntu ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/144887/creating-a-custom-ubuntu-iso)

My goal is to create an install disk which will install ubuntu with a specific suite of packages. Then use and re-use to initialize multiple systems for reproducing regression testing test bed scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a custom ubuntu ISO](http://superuser.com/questions/144887/creating-a-custom-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: Ubuntu isn't capable of doing an automated network install? I thought it had at least partial kickstart support.

Comment: Yes http://superuser.com/questions/144887/creating-a-custom-ubuntu-iso is close enough for me.  What is protocol here? Delete this question?

Comment: @ignacio: i'm not very familiar with it, but "kickstart" is a RedHat thing; i'm sure Debian has something similar but i'm not sure what it's called.

Comment: protocol is for someone to flag for moderator attention, or the community to vote to close as a duplicate.  in this case it was the former.  we leave duplicates existing to aid in searches, and closed so answers are posted to the "master" question.